# Why does this simple implicit stringToInt function cause a stack overflow?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-2.10

If I define a simple stringToInt function and store it as a val, everything works as expected, e.g.

```
scala> def stringToInt1: (String => Int) = _.toInt
stringToInt1: String => Int

scala> stringToInt1("1")
res0: Int = 1
```

However, if I then make that implicit, it causes a stack overflow:

```
scala> implicit def stringToInt2: (String => Int) = _.toInt
stringToInt2: String => Int

scala> stringToInt2("1")
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at .stringToInt2(<console>:7)
at $anonfun$stringToInt2$1.apply(<console>:7)
at $anonfun$stringToInt2$1.apply(<console>:7)
...
```

At first I suspected that this was because the underscore wasn't resolving to what I expected, but that's not the case, as this style of implicit val works fine for the following simple function:

```
scala> implicit def plusTwo: (Int => Int) = _ + 2
plusTwo: Int => Int

scala> plusTwo(2)
res2: Int = 4
```

If I define the parameter explicitly, no stack overflow:

```
scala> implicit def stringToInt3(s: String) = s.toInt
stringToInt3: (s: String)Int

scala> stringToInt3("1")
res3: Int = 1
```

*(If trying this yourself and this last case stack overflows, restart the scala console and redo this last step)*

So my question is, why is the original implicit not correctly resolving?

*Edit*

Ok digging a little deeper here, it seems that the problem is with the implicit conversion from String to StringOps. If we cut that out, it works fine:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
import scala.collection.immutable.StringOps

scala> implicit def stringToInt4: (String => Int) = new StringOps(_).toInt
stringToInt4: String => Int

scala> stringToInt4("1")
res4: Int = 1
```

But why would that implicit conversion be causing the issue?

Comment: As noted in a comment below, I'm aware that you would typically use a val not a def in the first two cases - the reason I've used def throughout in this question is to highlight the fact that the stack overflow is prevented by switching to a method that takes a string and returns an int.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding to the other replies.

There is **no** `toInt` method on `String`. Scala has to find an implicit conversion that will yield a type that has a `toInt` method.

Usually the `StringOps` conversion provides this `toInt`.
However `Int` **has** a `toInt` too, so scala finds your conversion from `String => Int` and decides that it has precedence over the `StringOps` conversion, thus applying it recursively.

This is why `StringToInt4` works, as you explicitly tell the compiler what conversion you want. Maybe you could write it as: `implicit def stringToInt5: (StringOps => Int) = _.toInt` or check how implicits are resolved and how one takes precedence over the other.

Comment: This makes absolute sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note what you are doing here:

```
scala> def stringToInt1: (String => Int) = _.toInt
stringToInt1: String => Int
```

You are defining a **method** (using `def`) that takes no parameters and returns a **function** from `String` to `Int`. Are you doing it this way on purpose, or is it just because you don't exactly understand the syntax?

You could have created a `val` instead:

```
val stringToInt1: (String => Int) = _.toInt
```

Now, `stringToInt1` is a `val` that contains a function to convert `String` to `Int`.

With your `stringToInt2`, Scala is recursively applying the method. I don't know why it does that in the case of `stringToInt2` but not with `plusTwo`.

Note that `stringToInt3` is not the same thing as `stringToInt1` and `stringToInt2`. It's a method that takes a `String` and returns an `Int`, not a method that takes no parameters and returns a function from `String` to `Int`.

Comment: So this was originally an implicit val, but I wanted to demonstrate that in the final step it was the fact that I'm changing it to a method that takes a String and returns an Int which is preventing the stack overflow, rather than the fact that I'm changing it from a val to a def. I thought the easiest way to avoid this confusion was to just use def throughout in this question.